# Div Layout - Repeating image help

Tags: css, photoshop, html, liquid-layout

I am trying to get the main content portion of my website to be wrapped in this notebook style look.

However on the main content portion I have a repeating image that sometimes cuts off at halfway through the image and doesn't look right, does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this either in Photoshop or with CSS ?

I have to maintain a liquid layout vertically, with the fixed width, however I want it to look like a notebook and not cut out and look trashy.

Here is the site with the example of what happens, thanks:

http://www.seth-duncan.com/Test/Notebook/notebook.html

Comment: I accessed the page and the image did not look 'cut-off'. It might be you are facing a browser-specific issue.. I was using Firefox 3.0.10 In what browser do you see the image cut-off? Also, consider a reset stylesheet to minimize cross-browser differences.

Comment: Try looking at it now. There is a blatent cutoff in the image now.

Comment: I think I see it now. You mean the place where the "notebook-Content.png" image 'connects' with the "notebook-Bottom.png" image towards the bottom of the page? Hmmm - haven't solved that type of problem before, sorry - if I some up with something I'll post.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample URL looks fine to me, but I think I know what you're talking about.  What you would need to do, I think, is force the `notebookContent` div to a height that's the next multiple up of the binder-spine image's height.  In jQuery, it'd be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = $('#notebookContent').height();
    var offset = height % 24;
    if(offset)
        $('#notebookContent').css('min-height', height + 24 - offset);
});
```

Comment: I thought it would need to be some sort of javascript workaround, so I was expecting something like this. The fact that it uses jQuery is perfect because that's my javascript library of choice. Thanks alot for the solution.

-Seth

Comment: Just be careful styling with JS, since if it's disabled all things could go to ruins.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a repeating image as a background, you should use

```
div {line-height: 24px; /* equal to the height of the image */
    }
```

and then all *other* images (in your case `content-Top.png` and `content-Bottom.png`) should be multiples of that image-, or line-, height. The problem you're having, I think, is that the bottom image is 31px tall, the top image is 41px tall and the repeating image is 24px tall. Those heights aren't going to mesh well.

Javascript can resolve this, but you'll probably find it easier to simply edit your images so that they share common heights.

I think `<br />` is equal to one line-height, and padding/margins between `<p>` tags should be adjusted to be equal to one (or whole multiples of) the line height to preserve the theme.

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) has a good article on this kind of thing over here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/settingtypeontheweb.

Also, because sometimes I just can't stop myself (*ah, insomnia, my old enemy...*), I cobbled together a demo-page for you, with the CSS on-page for your perusing-pleasure: http://www.davidrhysthomas.co.uk/so/notebook.html